# Spring tool suite latest version and PCF connection

Tags: spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I recently downloaded latest sts version 4.21 and I don't PCF connection in boot dashboard. Is there another way of connecting to cloud apps through STS. I was using 4.13 before and was able to connect.

I don't see an option to connect except docker in dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the extension for the dashboard in Spring Tools for Eclipse that allowed you to connect to Cloud Foundry instances is not maintained anymore and therefore no longer available.